# Include all library dependencies into an executable file Linux

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

thanks in advance. I need to use a linux C++ application on different machines   having all the dependencies of Opencv libraries.
Shall I install opencv on each machine or I can just use the libraries? 
If so how I can do that?

Comment: You could link the libraries statically, creating one huge executable that have most libraries in it. Or you could install OpenCV on each system, but you don't need to install the development packages only the base libraries.

Comment: Thank you! How it is possible to link all the libraries statically? I put -static in the makefile but it just link my libraries not Opencv' s !

Comment: I don't really recommend it, but add the `-static` flag when linking.

Comment: you can build static opencv libs with `cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV is  a library so installing it on the machine you intend to run a program that uses opencv is required. Follow the downloading instructions on http://opencv.org/downloads.html for the target you are interested in. You could also create an installation script along with your program if you intend to install it on many machines.